# Can I launch macOS Recovery Mode to reinstall macOS after I install a new hard drive?

Tags: macos, recovery

I plan to buy a used Mac Mini from 2011. I am a bit worried about getting a second-hand Mac Mini since there might be some virus on the Mac Mini and hence lose all of my data. Thus, upon purchase, I plan to replace the hard drive with what I already have. However, since I do not have access to any other macOS, I will not be able to make a recovery disk using a USB stick.

I read that Mac Mini has a Recovery Mode that allows reinstalling macOS if the Mac Mini is connected to the internet. Where are the recovery files located? Are they on the hard drive themselves? If yes, then I am worried upon replacing the hard drive I cannot reinstall the OS.

Comment: With respect to OS X 10.7 (Lion) and newer, if you have an Install OS X or macOS application, then usually (but not always) the installation files are stored locally inside the application. If the application has the installation files and the version is OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) or newer, the installation files can also be copied to a USB flash drive by executing the instructions given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Otherwise, the installation files are downloaded at the time you attempt to install OS X or macOS. If this does to answer your questions, then post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Macs have multiple types off recovery modes. One of them is located on an additional partition on your hard drive after installing macOS (10.7 or newer).

Another variant, called Internet Recovery, allows you to install a blank hard drive, then install macOS by downloading the recovery OS and install files from Apple's servers. More information can be found here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac, but the short version is:

> ◦   Command-R: Start up from the built-in macOS Recovery System. Use
> this key combination to reinstall the latest macOS that was installed
> on your system, or to use the other apps in macOS Recovery.

> ◦   Option-Command-R: Start up from macOS Recovery over the internet.
> Use this key combination to reinstall macOS and upgrade to the latest
> version of macOS that’s compatible with your Mac.

> ◦   Option-Shift-Command-R: Start up from macOS Recovery over the
> internet. Use this key combination to reinstall the version of macOS
> that came with your Mac or the closest version that’s still available.

Comment: For the 2011 Mac mini, the Option-Shift-Command-R key combination requires a firmware update included with Sierra or newer versions of macOS.